# Get Last Write Time is returning a strange value

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-7, last-modified

I'm trying to get the last modified date of a file in Windows 7 - I just edited it, so in the properties, the Last Modified value is listed as `11/30/2013 4:55 PM`.

However, when I access the file using:

```
DateTime lastMod = File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
```

I output the value:

```
MessageBox.Show(lastMod.toString());
```

This always gives `12/31/1600 6:00:00 PM`, regardless of which file I'm working with, regardless of creation time, modification time, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you're using the wrong file name. The [documentation for `GetLastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx) specifies:

> If the file described in the *path* parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

As that's the value you're getting, it suggests the file described in the *path* parameter quite possibly doesn't exist - so you should check the value of `file` and bear in mind that if it's a relative filename, it might not be relative to the directory you're expecting.

Comment: Must be, I'll take a look. Why is `GetLastWriteTime` designed to return a "default" value like that, rather than throw an exception?

Comment: @Wilson: I suspect that's just what the underlying file system API does. I agree it seems a little strange.