# GetLastWriteTime not accurate while files existing

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the last modified time for files in a directory. I loop through the directory and print the modified date. The output shows out of 10 files (Did this on other folders too with different number of files). 10 files appeared in the command prompt. All of them printed 12/31/1600.

How could I fix it so that it would print the correct date?

```
Dim strFilepath = "C:\Test" 'Test folder contains 10 files for test
Dim File As System.IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles()
Dim File1 As System.IO.FileInfo
Dim strLastModified As String

For Each File1 In File 'Loops the GetLastWriteTime
    strLastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFilepath & File.ToString()).ToShortDateString()
    Console.WriteLine(strLastModified)'Prints all 10 files but with the 12/31/1600 date
    'Files do exist, code goes into file, it loops through it but wrong date.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Last Write Time is returning a strange value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306688/get-last-write-time-is-returning-a-strange-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim gave you already the reason why your date is wron with his link to the dup.

You concat `strFilepath` and `File.ToString()` incorrectly because you are missing a backslash `\` between them and thus giving something like:
`C:\TestYourFile.txt`.

Additionally you are using the wrong variable in the For Each.
It should be `File1` instead of `File` (Thanks @Mark).

**Solution 1:**
That´s the reason why there is the [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

So Change

```
strLastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFilepath & File.ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

To

```
strLastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Path.Combine(strFilepath, File1.ToString())).ToShortDateString()
```

**Solution 2:**
Like Mark commented you could just use the [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx) property which makes it even easier:

```
strLastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(File1.FullName).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: It should also be `File1`, since `File` is the array of `FileInfo` (but `ToString()` probably gives the full path already).  Perhaps use `File1.FullPath` instead, so you don't have to combine anything?

Comment: Great notice @Mark I´ll incorporate it in my answer. Thanks!